# PHP Validate string characters are UK or US Keyboard characters

Tags: php, string, validation

What is the easiest or best way in PHP to validate true or false that a string only contains characters that can be typed using a standard US or UK keyboard with the keyboard language set to UK or US English?

To be a little more specific, I mean using a single key depression with or without using the shift key.

I think the characters are the following. 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\:;"'<,>.?/£ and Space

Comment: everyone has gone for pcre :/ there has to be some other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cover every ASCII character by `[ -~]` (i.e. range from space to tilde). Then just add `£` too and there you go (you might need to add other characters as well, such as `±` and `§`, but for that, have a look at the US and UK keyboard layouts).

Something like:

```
if(preg_match('#^[ -~£±§]*$#', $string)) {
    // valid
}
```

Comment: also, you might wanty to add `/[\x80-\xFF]/` matches non ascii chars

Comment: @RobertPitt: Well, OP only wants characters that only afford a key press or key press + shift key. I think `[\x80-\xFF]` covers a lot more.

Comment: This does not give me the results I expect. I am doing a $string = file_get_contents($url); That contains html of a post on my forum but the result of if(preg_match('#^[ -~£±§]*$#', $string)) says that it is not UK/US when I expeted it to say it was. On a 2nd file_get_contents($url) for a post that contains 相关的主题文章：if(preg_match('#^[ -~£±§]*$#', $string)) also says that it is not UK/US which is what I want but given that the first one also returned not UK/US then my test has not worked correctly.

Comment: @Colin Hill: What is inout for the first one? I never said that the regex is complete, there might be characters missing (e.g. you did not mention non printable characters like tab or return (then you would have to add `\s`)).

Comment: Have now tested this solution on a non html string and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression may be of use for you:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~\t ])*$/m
```

Use this as:

```
$result = (bool)preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~\t ])*$/m', $input);
```

Or create a reusable function from this code:

```
function testUsUkKeyboard($input) 
{
    return (bool)preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~\t ])*$/m', $input);
}
```

Comment: This does not give me the results I expect. See my comment answer to Felix below but basically the same result except both tests returned false when test 1 should be true and test 2 should be false.

Comment: Felix' comment is valid, you didn't mention non-printable characters.
You can enable multiline with the 'm' switch, and tabs with \t. like this:
/^([a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~\t ])*$/m

Edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I didn't mention that because I do $string = file_get_contents($url);
$string = str_replace("\r\n"," ",$string);
$string = str_replace("\t"," ",$string);
$string = str_replace(chr(9), " ", $string);
$string = str_replace(chr(10), " ", $string);
$string = str_replace(chr(13), " ", $string);

Comment: @Colin Hill: So what is the content you test against and does not work? If we'd know we could improve our answers.

Comment: Can you identify what characters are in the outcome of file_get_contents($url), that are not matched by the regular expression?
This might help solve the problem.

Comment: @Colin Hill: Regarding @rtuin's comment, you can just do a `preg_replace($one_of_our_patterns, '', $str)` and see which characters are left over.

Comment: Thanks very much for amending. Have just tested and the revised preg_match gives the expected results. Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to check is to check if chars exist rather then they do not, so first you would need a list of chars that do not exists, you can get these from the ascii range 128 - 255 where as 0 - 127 is the regular key set.

Tio create the invalid array uou can do:

```
$chars = range(128,255);
```

The above array would contain all the chars in the table below:
[image]

then you should check agains the string in question, people say use regex, but i dont really think thats needed

$string = "testing a plain string";

```
for($s=0;$s<strlen($string);$s++)
{
    if(in_array(ord($string[$s]),$chars))
    {
        //Invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: But `±` (241) is part of the US keyboard layout and `£` (156) of the UK one.

Comment: yea just like yours where you have to add on the specific chars, on mine you can just remove specific chars from the array. same sort of output.

Comment: My keyboard has no ±, and I am in the US.

Comment: @Brad: Mmh then the US keyboard layout in Mac OS X lies. The keyboard viewer shows me `§` next to the `1` and `±` when I press shift. Weird. Maybe it's a Mac thing.

Comment: Can't do it this way as it must test for valid US/UK only. Invalids will also be all other language characters and there are far too foreign languages to code.

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of different keyboard layouts.  I wish I had my old IBM PS/2 keyboard.  It would go up to F16.  :-D