# Regex to reject non-english characters?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

Is there a simple regex that will catch all non-english characters? It would need to allow common punctation and symbols, but no special characters such as Russian, Japanese, etc.

Looking for something to work in PHP.

Comment: Why are you wanting to restrict to english characters, but allow all punctuation‽ Are you really wanting to restrict input to ASCII characters?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619603/php-validate-string-characters-are-uk-or-us-keyboard-characters/4619747

Comment: @Anon - names and addresses commonly include apostrophes, commas, periods, etc. Want to normalize data so everything is in English.

Answer (score 2):

Since in your comment your referring to addresses, they might contain digits too. So:

```
preg_replace('/[^[:alpha:][:punct:][:digit:]]/u', utf8_encode($input), '');
```

Should replace your unwanted characters. The `[:alpha:]` class will only work, if your locale is set up correctly, though. If, for example, it's set to `de_DE`, not only "a" through "z" are regarded characters, but also "exotics" like "ä", "ö", "è", and the like.

Also, since you don't want "Russian, Japanese, etc.", note the `u` modifier. The input has to be UTF-8 encoded in order to not break it and give you wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Such as this one [^A-Za-z0-9\,\.\-]?

Comment: Habe fun with `"I'm breaking your regex."`.

Comment: `,`,`.` and `-` don't need to be escape inside a character group. For sure not `,` as it has no special meaning in regex anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This q/a seemed to handle it: [PHP Validate string characters are UK or US Keyboard characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619603/php-validate-string-characters-are-uk-or-us-keyboard-characters/4619747)

Answer (score 0):

use [hex codes](http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html), e.g. this cleans out all non-ascii characters as well as line endings, and replaces them with spaces. space (`\x20`) is deliberately left out of the range so that consecutive runs of spaces and/or special chars are replaced with a single space.

```
$clean = trim(preg_replace('/[^\x21-\x7E]+/', ' ', $input));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (strlen($str) == strlen(utf8_decode($str))) {

}
```

Comment: Not sure how that actually solves the problem posed. Some explanation would have been nice.