# java regex to filter out non-English text

Tags: java, regex

I found a few references to regex filtering out non-English but [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619603/php-validate-string-characters-are-uk-or-us-keyboard-characters/4619747) of them is in Java, aside from the fact that they are all referring to somewhat [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651899/regex-to-reject-non-english-characters) problems than what I am trying to solve:

1. Replace all non-English characters
   with a space.
2. Create a method that returns `true`
   if a string contains any non-English
   character.

By "English text" I mean not only actual letters and numbers but also punctuation.

So far, what I have been able to come with for goal #1 is quite simple:

```
String.replaceAll("\\W", " ")
```

In fact, so simple that I suspect that I am missing something... Do you spot any caveats in the above?

As for goal #2, I could simply `trim()` the string *after* the above `replaceAll()`, then check if it's empty. But... Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: there are a handful of legitimate English words which contain accented characters - eg "naïve".

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "English text"... i.e. is the following sentence considered "English text" or not? "Her fiancé's name is José Brontë."

Comment: @Spudley @Nate You are both correct of course. For my particular case, "Her fiancé's name is José Brontë." is **not** considered *all* English and thus the method should return `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In fact, so simple that I suspect that I am missing something... Do you spot any caveats in the above?

`\W` is equivalent to `[^\w]`, and `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. Using `\W` will replace **everything** which isn't a letter, a number, or an underscore — like tabs and newline characters. Whether or not that's a problem is really up to you.

> By "English text" I mean not only actual letters and numbers but also punctuation.

In that case, you might want to use a character class which omits punctuation; something like

```
[^\w.,;:'"]
```

> Create a method that returns true if a string contains any non-English character.

Use [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W");

boolean containsSpecialChars(String string)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    return m.find();
}
```

Comment: -1 This won't work. You need to use `matcher.find()` or change your regex to match the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. I assume the text may contain English words, punctuation marks and standard ascii symbols such as #, %, @ etc.

```js
private static final String IS_ENGLISH_REGEX = "^[ \\w \\d \\s \\. \\& \\+ \\- \\, \\! \\@ \\# \\$ \\% \\^ \\* \\( \\) \\; \\\\ \\/ \\| \\< \\> \\\" \\' \\? \\= \\: \\[ \\] ]*$";

private static boolean isEnglish(String text) {
  if (text == null) {
   return false;
  }
  return text.matches(IS_ENGLISH_REGEX);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
  private static boolean isEnglish(String text) {
        CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder();
        CharsetEncoder isoEncoder = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder();
        return  asciiEncoder.canEncode(text) || isoEncoder.canEncode(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an english word is made up of characters from: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

To return true if a string contains any non-English character, use [`string.matches`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
return !string.matches("^\\w+$");
```

Comment: @dogbane Why the `^` and the `$`?

Comment: @regex-rookie it's not necessary, but I'm making it clear that I am matching the whole string from start to end.

Comment: @dogbane Your regex doesn't seem to work with a string that starts (or ends) with non-English characters. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @regex-rookie yes it does. My statement returns true as required.

Comment: @dogbane Your regex still doesn't work. Try placing an all-English text with only one non-English character in it on http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html and see what I mean.

Comment: @dogbane However, if I remove the leading `^` and trailing `$`, matches are found.

Comment: have you tried my statement? It returns true. Isnt that what you want?