# How to remove non English characters from string using java?

Tags: java

**I want to remove any non English characters from string.**

For example:
String str = "Instagram पोस्ट: SMOKE VODKA comes in Classic and...";

from above given string I want to remove पोस्ट.

How can I do that ?

Comment: This should solve your problem. [](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204599/9226116)https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204599/9226116

Comment: This should solve your problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204599/9226116](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204599/9226116)